# Finding the sequence of the recursive formula

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

The sequence is defined by

$$ x_0 = 1 $$

$$ x_n = {1 + x_{n-1}}^(0.5) $$

I am trying to find out the limit to the nth integer but for some reason my x_1 value does not carry to the third element.

Here is my code:

```
def recursion (x):
x_0 = 1
x_1 = (2)**(0.5)
lst = [1]

while  len(lst) <= x:
    x_0, x_1 = x_1, ((1+x_0)**(1/2))
    lst.append(x_0)
print(lst)
```

It works for the first 2 elements only.

[image]

This is what I want it to do[image]

Comment: Sorry I do not use how to use Latex here. Apologies

Comment: You can't use Latex on SO. Could you give a better problem description than *"finding it hard"*? See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
x_0, x_1 = x_1, ((1+x_0)**(1/2))
```

You're calculating `x_0` and `x_1` at the same time, but your formula for the new `x_1` expects `x_0` to have already been updated. If you split them up, you should get what you expect:

```
x_0 = x_1
x_1 = (1+x_0)**(1/2)
```

You're keeping more values than you need to, though. You only need one initializing value, and instead of having intermediate variables you can just read from the top of the `lst`:

```
lst = [1.0]
while len(lst) <= x:
    lst.append((1+lst[-1])**(0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with `python-3.x` but your seem to be running this with Python 2. I don't know why, but in Python2 I get `[1, 1.4142135623730951, 1, 1.0, 1, 1.0, 1, 1.0, 1, 1.0, 1]` whereas Python3 returns the correct sequence.